# Getting result of a spawned function in Erlang

Tags: list, concurrency, parallel-processing, functional-programming, erlang

My objective at the moment is to write Erlang code calculating a list of N elements, where each element is a factorial of it's "index" (so, for N = 10 I would like to get [1!, 2!, 3!, ..., 10!]). What's more, I would like every element to be calculated in a seperate process (I know it is simply inefficient, but I am expected to implement it and compare its efficiency with other methods later).

In my code, I wanted to use one function as a "loop" over given N, that for N, N-1, N-2... spawns a process which calculates factorial(N) and sends the result to some "collecting" function, which packs received results into a list. I know my concept is probably overcomplicated, so hopefully the code will explain a bit more:

```
messageFactorial(N, listPID) ->
    listPID ! factorial(N).      %% send calculated factorial to "collector".

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
nProcessesFactorialList(-1) ->
    ok;
nProcessesFactorialList(N) ->
    spawn(pFactorial, messageFactorial, [N, listPID]),   %%for each N spawn...
    nProcessesFactorialList(N-1).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
listPrepare(List) ->            %% "collector", for the last factorial returns
    receive                     %% a list of factorials (1! = 1).
        1 -> List;
        X ->
            listPrepare([X | List])
    end.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
startProcessesFactorialList(N) ->
    register(listPID, spawn(pFactorial, listPrepare, [[]])),
    nProcessesFactorialList(N).
```

I guess it shall work, by which I mean that listPrepare finally returns a list of factorials. But the problem is, I do not know how to get that list, how to get what it returned? As for now my code returns ok, as this is what nProcessesFactorialList returns at its finish. I thought about sending the List of results from listPrepare to nProcessesFactorialList in the end, but then it would also need to be a registered process, from which I wouldn't know how to recover that list.

So basically, how to get the result from a registered process running listPrepare (which is my list of factorials)? If my code is not right at all, I would ask for a suggestion of how to get it better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My way how to do this sort of tasks is

```
-module(par_fact).

-export([calc/1]).

fact(X) -> fact(X, 1).

fact(0, R) -> R;
fact(X, R) when X > 0 -> fact(X-1, R*X).

calc(N) ->
    Self = self(),
    Pids = [ spawn_link(fun() -> Self ! {self(), {X, fact(X)}} end)
            || X <- lists:seq(1, N) ],
    [ receive {Pid, R} -> R end || Pid <- Pids ].
```

and result:

```
> par_fact:calc(25).
[{1,1},
 {2,2},
 {3,6},
 {4,24},
 {5,120},
 {6,720},
 {7,5040},
 {8,40320},
 {9,362880},
 {10,3628800},
 {11,39916800},
 {12,479001600},
 {13,6227020800},
 {14,87178291200},
 {15,1307674368000},
 {16,20922789888000},
 {17,355687428096000},
 {18,6402373705728000},
 {19,121645100408832000},
 {20,2432902008176640000},
 {21,51090942171709440000},
 {22,1124000727777607680000},
 {23,25852016738884976640000},
 {24,620448401733239439360000},
 {25,15511210043330985984000000}]
```

Comment: That is some very clean code indeed. May sound lame, but I never got the idea of actually sending results to spawning proces and now I do!

Comment: @3yakuya: Later I used this code for my presentation. There is like 80% of whole Erlang language in just ten lines of code. There is a single assignment, recursion, pattern matching, expressions, list comprehensions, spawn, link, send, receive, local and external function call, tuples, lists, module and functions declarations, multiple function clauses, guards, funs, BIFs. There is minimum left.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that your `listPrepare` process doesn't do anything with the result. Try to print it in the end.

The second problem is that you don't wait for all the processes to finish, but for process that sends `1` and this is the quickest factorial to calculate. So this message will surely be received before the more complex will be calculated, and you'll end up with only a few responses.

I had answered a bit similar question on the parallel work with many processes here: [Create list across many processes in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823512/create-list-across-many-processes-in-erlang/19824866#19824866) Maybe that one will help you.

Comment: Each of the processes will finish only after they've done everything they are supposed to. And the first factorial to calculate is N!, as nProcessFactorialList goes from N to -1. That process of calculating 1 is launched as the last one, and as I printed results before appending them to the list, they were correct and in correct order. If problems appeared, I would send each info with some parameters to sort incomming messages. Problem is not printing the list, but getting it returned in the end.

Comment: Try some big number that will require at least couple of seconds to calculate if you don't believe me.

Comment: 3000 goes fine it appears. I wondered, whether it would be a problem, but it appeared to me that as we calculate from the greatest numbers, when we go one step down (so calculate (n-1)!) we have already calculated the biggest multiplification (n * (n-1)) for the earlier-called process. Still, shall any errors you mentioned occur, I will just send {Result, Date} to the collector, so that answers are packed into the list in a proper order, thank you.

Comment: I have add some comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you this solution:

```
-export([launch/1,fact/2]).

launch(N) ->
    launch(N,N).

%   launch(Current,Total)
%   when all processes are launched go to the result collect phase 
launch(-1,N) -> collect(N+1);
launch(I,N) ->
%   fact will be executed in a new process, so the normal way to get the answer is by message passing
%   need to give the current process pid to get the answer back from the spawned process 
    spawn(?MODULE,fact,[I,self()]),
%   loop until all processes are launched
    launch(I-1,N).

% simply send the result to Pid.
fact(N,Pid) -> Pid ! {N,fact_1(N,1)}.

fact_1(I,R) when I < 2 -> R;
fact_1(I,R) -> fact_1(I-1,R*I).

% init the collect phase with an empty result list
collect(N) -> collect(N,[]).

% collect(Remaining_result_to_collect,Result_list)
collect(0,L) -> L;
% accumulate the results in L and loop until all messages are received
collect(N,L) ->
    receive
        R -> collect(N-1,[R|L])
    end.
```

but a much more straight (single process) solution could be:

```
1> F = fun(N) -> lists:foldl(fun(I,[{X,R}|Q]) -> [{I,R*I},{X,R}|Q] end, [{0,1}], lists:seq(1,N)) end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.6.80484245>
2> F(6).
[{6,720},{5,120},{4,24},{3,6},{2,2},{1,1},{0,1}]
```

**[edit]**

On a system with multicore, cache and an multitask underlying system, there is absolutly no guarantee on the order of execution, same thing on message sending. The only guarantee is in the message queue where you know that you will analyse the messages according to the order of message reception. So I agree with Dmitry, your stop condition is not 100% effective.

In addition, using `startProcessesFactorialList`, you spawn `listPrepare` which collect effectively all the factorial values (except 1!) and then simply forget the result at the end of the process, I guess this code snippet is not exactly the one you use for testing.