# Erlang spawning processes

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Following is the program in which i have tried to spawn 3 processes form a method called best. I want to receive response from all the processes and store them in a tuple but I am able to get only one response.

```
test() ->
    receive
     {From,N} -> From!{self(),N},
                 loop()
    end.

best(N) ->    
     Aid=spawn(fun t:loop/0),
     Aid ! {self(),N},
     Bid=spawn(fun t:loop/0),
     Bid ! {self(),N},
     Cid=spawn(fun t:loop/0),
     Cid ! {self(),N},
     receive 
        {Pid,Response} ->{Response}
     end.
```

Can someone please help me out with this probem

Comment: For spawning multiple processes I'm using this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/20573151/49197

Comment: The function name is test() , I think it should be loop()

Answer (score 1):

Your receive bloc, in the best/2 function exit as soon as it receives one message. If you launch this code in the shell, you can verify that the other message are still in the message queue with the function flush(). (The code you posted is missing the t:loop/0 function, I guess it will compute something based on N and return the answer via a message to the spawner)

To be able to receive more than one message, you must put the receive bloc in a "loop" that recursively calls itself until it got all answers. You will have to use a variable that allows the recursive loop to know when it is finished (number of answers expected, list of processes that should answer...) and collect the answers in a list variable for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
-module(wy).
-compile(export_all).

loop() ->
    Self = self(),
    receive 
    {From, Ref, N} ->
        From ! {Self, Ref, N * N}
    end.

receive_result(Ref) ->
    receive 
    {Pid, Ref, R} ->
        io:format("process ~p: ~p~n", [Pid, R]), 
        receive_result(Ref)
    after 10 ->
        ok
    end.
best() ->
    APid = spawn(fun loop/0),
    BPid = spawn(fun loop/0),
    CPid = spawn(fun loop/0),

    Self = self(),
    Ref  = make_ref(),
    APid ! {Self, Ref, 2},
    BPid ! {Self, Ref, 3},
    CPid ! {Self, Ref, 4},

    receive_result(Ref).
```

You can follow this small code. The result is:

```
9> wy:best().
process <0.77.0>: 4
process <0.78.0>: 9
process <0.79.0>: 16
ok
```