# How to sort a list based on the original list?

Tags: erlang

how to sort a list based on another list, example :

> List = [1,2,3,4,5].

I have a function which sends this list and a function to apply on the elements of the list to a worker, example :

> sender(List,F)
>
> worker() will apply F(elements of the list)

and send back the elements one by one the the sender function.
Here, sending the result of elements may not be in the same order as the sender sent.
so, if I send [1,2,3,4,5], the worker probably sends back the list in this way

> [result(2),result(5),result(1),result(4),result(3)]

My question is : how to sort the list of the result based on the original list

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20573151/49197

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr; The short answer here is if you want to preserve ordering, the workers will need to know the index of the element they are processing and return it to the caller so the list can be reassembled**

I would suggest sending along the index of the item to each worker (e.g. `F(Element, Index)`). Then instead of just sending the result back send the result and the index (`{Index, Result}`) so when you get the result from each worker you know where it belongs in the list. Then use a selective receive to put them back in order:

```
results_from_workers(Max) ->
  results_from_workers(Max, 0, []).

results_from_workers(Max, Num, NewList) when Num > Max ->
  % If the next number is greater than the max, reverse the list and return it
  lists:reverse(NewList);
results_from_workers(Max, Num, NewList) ->
  % Receive the result for the next number
  receive
    {Num, Result} ->
      results_from_workers(Num + 1, [Result|NewList])
  end.

% Then call your code that starts the workers
sender(List,F),

% Then call `results_from_workers/1` with the length of the list being processed, it should return the new list
NewList = results_from_workers(length(List)).
```

The downside to this is that if a processes crashes the results_from_workers process will hang waiting for the result from the crashed process. You should be linking your worker processes to the process that started them, so this shouldn't be an issue. If for some reason you can't or don't want to link to the worker processes, can you use a `after Timeout -> failed` clause in the receive, with `Timeout` being a integer representing the timeout in milliseconds. Note that if you have a worker that takes longer than expected the timeout clause might be executed, leaving you without a result.

Comment: The basic idea of adding more info to the original list (i.e., indices of elements) is what is important here. The rest of the answer is speculative and includes a lot of info that was not requested.

Comment: aronisstav, thanks added a tldr to my answer.

Comment: Thank you , is there a defined function in erlang to check the indexes of elements of a list?

Comment: `lists:nth/2` returns the element at the specified index. Beyond that you'll need to write your own functions or list comprehensions.