# How to await multiple tasks in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, async-await, task, elixir

I want to perform multiple tasks concurrently. In Javascript, I would do:

```
async function cook_an_egg() {}

async function take_shower() {}

async function call_mum() {}

await Promise.all([cook_an_egg(), take_shower(), call_mum()])
```

How do I achieve `Promise.all` in Elixir Task module? 
From [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await/2), seems you can only `await` 1 task; define 1 function inside each `task`; and apply only the same function to multiple items with `async_stream` .

Comment: Use Elixir equivalent of http://stackoverflow.com/a/20573151/49197

Comment: There's also `Task.yield_many/2`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can map `await` function to a list of task refs. 
Something like

```
tasks = Enum.reduce(0..9, [], fn _, acc -> 
  [Task.async(&any_job/0) | acc]
end)

Enum.map(tasks, &Task.await/1)
```

Comment: Interesting, I would expect the first `Task.await` inside the map function will block the process from involking the next `await` until it's finished. Am I right that `Task.await` is not blocking any 'Enum' methods by design?

Comment: Does it matter? Say that the first process takes the longest - so you wait for that, then when the first await is done, all the others finish immediately as their processes are done.

Comment: Well, it matters when I don't understand how it behaves. Would you please have a look at this code: http://elixirplayground.com?gist=4682af479dbb1a4510b7deef373ca51e. I really don't get how the log `"done async 2"` comes before the second `"starting new task"`.

Comment: Your both functions (async_1 and _2) are writing to the IO device in async manner, so you don't need to await on them to see that side effect, but it works perfectly fine when you need the results of those 2 functions ([1,2])

Comment: Each `Task.await` does block until finished, and this can certainly matter if we want to enforce a timeout. I've added an answer that demonstrates the problem with this approach and provides a more robust (though also more verbose) solution with `Task.yield_many`.

Answer (score 29):

### For Elixir v1.11.0 and up

[`Task.await_many`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await_many/2) is designed to do exactly this. It handles the overall timeout correctly and should do the least surprising thing in the face of exits, timeouts, etc.

```
tasks = [
  Task.async(fn -> cook_an_egg(:medium) end),
  Task.async(fn -> take_shower(10) end),
  Task.async(fn -> call_mum() end),
]

Task.await_many(tasks)
```

### For older versions

A more bulletproof solution than `Task.await` is [`Task.yield_many`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/2). Unfortunately, it's a little more verbose because it leaves us in charge of handling timed-out and dead tasks ourselves. If we want to mimic the behavior of `async`/`await` and exit when something goes wrong, it will look like this:

```
tasks = [
  Task.async(fn -> cook_an_egg(:medium) end),
  Task.async(fn -> take_shower(10) end),
  Task.async(fn -> call_mum() end),
]

Task.yield_many(tasks)
|> Enum.map(fn {task, result} ->
  case result do
    nil ->
      Task.shutdown(task, :brutal_kill)
      exit(:timeout)
    {:exit, reason} ->
      exit(reason)
    {:ok, result} ->
      result
  end
end)
```

### Why not use `await`?

Using `Task.await` will work in simple situations, but if you care about the timeout you can get yourself into trouble. Mapping across the list happens sequentially, which means each `Task.await` will block for up to the specified timeout before giving a result, at which point we move to the next item in the list and block *again* for up to the full timeout.

We can demonstrate this behavior by creating a list of tasks that sleep for 1-8 seconds. With the default timeout of 5 seconds, some of these tasks would be killed when called directly with `await`, but when we enumerate across the list, that's not what happens:

```
for ms <- [2_000, 4_000, 6_000] do
  Task.async(fn -> Process.sleep(ms); ms end)
end
|> Enum.map(&Task.await/1)

# Blocks for 6 seconds
# => [2000, 4000, 6000]

# Each `await` picks up after the previous one finishes with a fresh 5s timeout.
# Since each one blocks for 2s before finishing, no timeout is triggered
# but the total run time runs over.
 
# async(2s)--await(2s)-->(2s)
# async(4s)                  --await(2s)-->(4s)
# async(6s)                                    --await(2s)-->(6s)
```

If we modify this to use `Task.yield_many`, we can get the desired behavior:

```
for ms <- [2_000, 4_000, 6_000] do
  Task.async(fn -> Process.sleep(ms); ms end)
end
|> Task.yield_many(5000)
|> Enum.map(fn {t, res} -> res || Task.shutdown(t, :brutal_kill) end)

# Blocks for 5 seconds
# => [{:ok, 2000}, {:ok, 4000}, nil]
```

Comment: This really looks more robust and exhaustive. Thanks!

Comment: nice! can you give more details on why in 1st example it waits blocks for 10 secs instead of the default 5

Comment: I changed the example and added a little more explanation to hopefully explain better why the timeouts work the way they do. I also realized I should add a link to the new `await_many` function that has been added to Elixir, since I proposed it exactly to help with this problem .

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, Elixir's Task module has sprouted new powers.

There is both [`Task.await_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await_many/1) and [`Task.yield_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/1), which do what they sound like.

To answer the example in the original question:

```
cook_an_egg = Task.async(fn -> end)
take_shower = Task.async(fn -> end)
call_mum = Task.async(fn -> end)
Task.await_many([cook_an_egg, take_shower, call_mum])
```

---

There is no analog to `Promise.any`, but you could write one pretty easily using [`Task.yield_many/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#yield_many/1)